# How to play a sound with an attack / sustain (loop) / decay on iOS

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, avaudioplayer, openal, audioqueue

I have a need in my application for playing a song in three distinct, but seamless parts: The beginning (one-shot attack) which will seamlessly transition into the loop (sustain), which will finish with the end (decay).  The sounds are all setup and created to be seamless.  I used to use SoundEngine to do this and it worked great (2.0 SDK), but that's been long deprecated for a while.

Any good tutorials or libraries for doing this?